# 301 Redirection from Old Magento2 URLs to SEO-Friendly URLs

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, product-urls

In my Magento2, some products have URLs that include the product id, such as the URL below.

```
https://www.example.com/catalog/product/view/id/*
```

and indexed with Google as well.

Now i have regenerated the product URL, and it's showing like SEO-friendly

```
https://www.example.com/seo-friendly.html
```

Now I want to update these URLs with Google-indexed URLs.  How can we achieve this?

As this format `catalog/product/view/id/*` is the base format of the URL, how can we force Magento to redirect these types of urls to SEO-friendly urls with 301 redirection?

Answer (score 3):

You can create 301 redirection for catalog/product/view path url to seo friendly url by below approach.

**Step 1: You can override catalog/product/view controller execute method.**

**Step 2: Then you check if current opened product url has catalog/product/view pattern.**

```
public function execute(){
$urlReqPath = $this->getCurrentUrlPath();

if ($this->containsCatalogProductView($urlReqPath)) {
$productId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
$product = $this->productModel->load($productId);

// Check if the product exists
if ($product->getId()) {
    $url = $product->getProductUrl();
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $resultRedirect->setHttpResponseCode(301);
    $resultRedirect->setUrl($url);
    return $resultRedirect;
} else {
  parent::execute();
}
}

public function getCurrentUrlPath(){
    return $this->urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();
}

public function containsCatalogProductView($inputString)
{
    return strpos($inputString, 'catalog/product/view') !== false;
}
```

Please let me know, if have any doubt's regarding the same. And Don't forget to up-vote the answer :).

Comment: +1 from my side, I will check this and update you @Nikunj

Answer (score 0):

You Configure automatic URL Redirect.

- Log in to the **Admin Panel**
- Go to **Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog**
- Select the drop-down menu of the **Search Engine Optimization section**
- Set Create Permanent Redirect for URLs if **URL Key Changed to ‘Yes’**
- Save your settings from the **"Save Config"** button.

Comment: It's already enabled